# ¿Llenar una JTable con un arreglo de tres dimensiones?

Tags: java

Tengo en *Java* un arreglo de tres dimensiones:

```
arreglo[numerodetablas][][]
```

La primera dimensión determina el número de tablas y las otras son las dimensiones de cada tabla. ¿Cómo programar esto en tablas *JTable*?

Answer (score 1):

Deberías hacerlo con un `for` por dimensión. El primero generaría las tablas y luego las otras dos dimensiones los valores para rellenar dicha tabla.

Podría ser algo así:

```
Object [][][] array = new Object[5][10][10];
// Suponemos que el array tiene valores

for(int n = 0; n < 5; n++){
    Vector model = new Vector();
    Vector row = new Vector();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        row = new Vector();

        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            row.add(array[n][i][j]);
        }

        model.add(row);
    }

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    // Tabla creada para cada dimension n del array tridimensional
}
```